# Does change in metric signature affect the result of loop integrals in momentum space?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, metric-tensor, conventions

I was wondering whether the change in metric signature affect the standard results of loop integrals. Suppose a rank-4 tensor integral's result is known, does changing the metric signature for the momenta change that result, or it remains intact. Any explanation or proof would be appreciated.

Comment: Physics should not depend on whether we use the East Coast or the West Coast sign convention for the metric.

Comment: Why don't you redefine some of the co-ordinates by a factor of $i$ and check?